# Como fazer select em colunas específicas e continuar recebendo uma lista da entidade e não um array de Object?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

Tendo a seguente classe:

```
  public class Usuario { 
        private Integer id; 
        private Email email;
        private String nome;
        private String sobrenome;
        private String senha;
        private String usuario;
        private List<Grupo> grupos;

        //getters e setters

    }
```

Para fazer um selct somente nas colunas nome, sobrenome e email eu posso fazer assim:

```
SELECT u.nome, u.sobrenome, u.email FROM Usuario u
```

Mas neste caso, eu recebo de volta uma lista de Object[], onde cada posição do array equivale à uma das colunas especificadas.

Mas existe alguma forma de fazer um select desses e retornar uma List de Usuario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma lista de entidade não será possível nesse seu modelo, mas o quê poderá ser feito é criar uma classe com os atributos que você precisa e disponibilizar um construtor com esses atributos. Veja:

```
public class UsuarioAtributos {
  private String nome;
  private String sobreNome;
  private String email;

public UsuarioAtributos(String nome, String sobreNome, String email) {
    // definir os mapeamentos
}
```

E na sua consulta você passaria definir dessa forma:

```
SELECT new meu.pacote.UsuarioAtributos(u.nome, u.sobreNome, u.email) FROM Usuario u
```

O retorno será uma lista de **UsuarioAtributos** e não mais um array de Object.

Answer (score 1):

Completando a resposta do escapistabr, é possível fazer, e é praticamente o que ele já disse na resposta dele:

Supondo que sua classe Usuario está no seguinte pacote: br.com.meusistema.entidades.

Ai você pode fazer a jpql assim:

```
SELECT new br.com.meusistema.entidades.Usuario(u.nome, u.sobrenome, u.email) from Usuario u
```

Repare no **new** e no caminho da classe.

E seria necessário adicionar um construtor corresponde na classe Usuario:

```
public class Usuario { 
        private Integer id; 
        private Email email;
        private String nome;
        private String sobrenome;
        private String senha;
        private String usuario;
        private List<Grupo> grupos;

        //construtor padrão
        public Usuario(){}

        //construtor corresponde a busca
        public Usuario(String nome, String sobrenome, String email){        
            this.nome = nome;
            this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
            this.email = email;
        }

        //getters e setters

    }
```

Resumindo: você precisa de um construtor com os atributos que você está buscando no select, **e adicionar o new e o caminho da classe na JPQL**, assim você conseguiria receber uma List como retorno da query, pois para cada linha da tabela será instanciado um objeto usando o construtor que corresponde aos atributos da query, caso você não tenha um construtor correspondente, será laçada uma exceção dizendo que não existe um construtor apropriado.

Comment: realmente faltou o new. Vou editar a minha resposta. +1

Comment: Isso. E só lembrando que não é necessário criar uma nova classe, com o construtor apropriando é possível fazer a query somente com a classe Usuario.

Comment: Exatamente Resende, fiz o teste aqui e funcionou sim. Obrigado a você e ao escapistabr pelas respostas, me ajudaram a fazer exatamente o que eu queria.